# Argument of type 'Sound' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm writing a simple react-native app using typescript and expo-cli.
I've imported expo-av but I'm having some trouble when trying to play audio.
I'm following [this guide][1] but it's written in javascript and I guess that's the problem here since it's complaining about types.

```
  import { Audio } from "expo-av";
  
  export const useAudio = () => {
    const [sound, setSound] = useState();

    const playSound = async () => {
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync( // this line causes the error
        require("../assets/sound/ding.mp3")
      );
    setSound(sound);
    await sound.playAsync();
  }
};

[![error message][2]][2]


  [1]: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v42.0.0/sdk/audio/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqDgC.png
```

Comment: where is a call of playSound?

Comment: @AlexShtromberg Nowhere at this point since I got an error in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are initializing `sound` state as undefined (`useState()`), Typescript doesn't allow setting `sound` to any other type.

I suggest you type `sound` like this:

```
    const [sound, setSound] = useState<Audio.Sound|null>(null);
```

So, `sound` is `null` initially but may be set to another object of type `Audio.Sound` based on the logic of the component. which requires you to always be careful whether `sound` is `null` or not before using any of its properties.

for example:

```
sound.play() // first check if it isn't null!
```